# AJAX Data Return & Dynamically Altering Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following table on my page, with multiple rows, but to keep it short, I'm pairing it down to one.

```
<tr id="668">
  <td class="tableCheckBox"><div class="icheckbox_flat-blue" style="position: relative;"><input class="sendCheckbox" name="send[]" value="668" form="sendBillsForm" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" type="checkbox"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;"></ins></div></td>
  <td class="manifestNo">0882129</td>
  <td class="DriverName">Thomas Bryant<br><button type="button" class="btn btn-default arrivalDetailsButton" data-button="668">Signature</button></td>
  <td class="truckMake">54792</td>
  <td class="truckColor">Red</td>
  <td style="text-align: center" class="arrivedStatus"><div style="font-size:16px; font-weight: bold">6:32 AM</div>March 7, 2018<br>
    <div class="unloadStatusSpan">
      <span class="label bg-red">IN QUEUE</span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td><div class="btn-group-vertical">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning arrivalNotifyButton" data-button="668"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Notify</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success arrivalStatusButton" data-button="668"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Status</button>
  </div></td>
</tr>
```

Now, when I click the button with the class of `arrivalStatusButton`, it pulls up a modal where you can choose the status. From there you click submit and it POSTS it to the database, and is SUPPOSED to change the status span in the table row in the div class `unloadStatusSpan`.

Below is my script which includes first opening up the modal, and then the submission of data, where the returned actions are supposed to change the span with whatever is returned in the successful POST. Unfortunately, when I use this, the data is successfully posted, but the span is not successfully altered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.arrivalStatusButton').click(function(){
    var arrivalID = $.parseJSON($(this).attr('data-button'));
    $('.modal-title').text('Change Arrival Status');
    $('#arrivalStatus').modal('show');
    $('#arrivalStatusBody').html('<select name="arrivalStatus"><option value="1">In Queue</option><option value="2">Unloading</option><option value="3">Unloaded</option><option value="4">Delayed</option><option value="5">Other</option>');
    $('.modal-footer').html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success changeArrivalStatus" id="changeArrivalStatus" data-dismiss="modal" data-button="'+arrivalID+'"><span id="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Change Arrival Status</button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>');
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".changeArrivalStatus", function(){
    var $a = $(this);
    var $arrivalID = $.parseJSON($a.attr('data-button'));
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url: '/carrier/dispatch/arrivals/statusChange',
      dataType:'json',
      data: {
        'arrivalStatus':$('select[name=arrivalStatus]').val(),
        'arrival': $arrivalID,
        '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
        $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

        if ((data.errors)) {
          setTimeout(function () {
            $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
            toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
          }, 500);

          if (data.errors.title) {
            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
          }
          if (data.errors.content) {
            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
          }
        } else { //THIS "SUCCESS ALERT" WORKS TOO, but just beneath it, where I search for the element to change, nothing happens...//
          toastr.success('The arrival status has been successfully changed.', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
          var $statusSpan = $document.find("tr[id='"+$arrivalID+"']").children('.unloadStatusSpan');
          if(data.details.unloadStatus == 1){
            $statusSpan.html('<span class="label bg-red unloadStatusSpan">IN QUEUE</span>');
          }
          if(data.details.unloadStatus == 2){
            $statusSpan.html('<span class="label bg-yellow unloadStatusSpan">UNLOADING</span>');
          }
          if(data.details.unloadStatus == 3){
            $statusSpan.html('<span class="label bg-green unloadStatusSpan">UNLOADED</span>');
          }
        }
      },

      error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
          alert('Internal error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
        } else {
          console.log('An error has occured.');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Have you done any debug?whats in data argument returned from success?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://api.jquery.com/children/ says

> .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree

However, in your DOM, "unloadStatusSpan" is two levels down from your tr (the td is the first level).

```
var $statusSpan = $document.find("tr[id='"+$arrivalID+"']").children('.unloadStatusSpan');
```

can be changed simply to

```
var $statusSpan = $("#"+$arrivalID+" .unloadStatusSpan");
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your answer worked perfectly!